# Bash cmdlist using { } doesn't work

Tags: bash

I read about commands within the `{ }`, happen in the current shell without start a new so The following commands:

`for i in {1..50000} ;  do echo $i ; done`

should works the same as

`for i in {1..50000} ; { do echo $i } ; done`

but it gives me an error:

`zsh: parse error near`do'`

any idea?

Comment: your error says `zsh` but your question says `bash`. Which one are you using?

Comment: Oups, I did not see that when I wrote my answer. Hope it is also valid for zsh.

Comment: @dogbane sorry for the confusion, I'm using bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mixed-up (and made a typo) two concepts.
The documentation http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html
in section 3.2.4.3 says:

```
   {}
     { list; }
    Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes
    the list to be executed in the current shell context.
    No subshell is created. 
    The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.
```

They explain it is different from `(list; )` with parenthesis (not braces) that would invoke a subshell.
Further in the doc, in 3.5.1, they explain braces expansion (the brace content is expanded as a list of values).

Actually:

```
for i in {1..50000}
```

is a brace expansion: the content between the braces is replaced by a list of integer.

What you wanted to do after the for command, should write:

```
for i in {1..5000}
do
{ echo $ii ; echo "something else or run a command"; echo "maybe another"; }
done
```

Notes:

1/ {  MUST be followed by a space.

2/ the do command should not be in the brace

3/ the list of commands must end with a semicolon ;

Comment: `{` isn't a command (it marks the beginning of a group command, however), but it's not a metacharacter either, which is why the space is required.